# cocos2d-iphone games stop playing background music sometimes

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

`cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`.

I have noticed this with other cocos2d-iphone games installed in my device, like Kingdom Rush.

Basically, most of the times, the audio is fine (almost always). But suddenly, at an unexpected moment, **the background music stops playing and only the sound effects work**. Sometimes, killing the application will not be enough to fix it.

With my `cocos2d-iphone` game this happens as well, with no hint in the console. I use `SimpleAudioEngine` to play background music and sound effects.

Killing my application, restarting Xcode will not fix it. I usually just ignore the problem and, in the near future, it is suddenly gone. I suspect that rebooting the device tends to fix this, but that's beyond the point: I should know *why* is it happening.

I also tried preloading my background music. Doesn't change a thing.

I believe I have experienced this problem with both .mp3 and .wav formats.

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

No idea to the exact reason, but I can think of a few:

- memory warning causes audio stream to be interrupted
- audio interruptions (calendar notification, incoming SMS/call) not handled properly by CocosDenshion
- other streaming music is played (ie perhaps videoplayer, iPod music player)
- music isn't streamed but buffered, which means music is fighting over audio buffers with all other effects - eventually so many audio effects are played that older buffers have to cancel playback (which might be the music) in order to allow the new effect to play
- defective device (since it happens in other apps …)
- bug in CocosDenshion (check the cocos2d issue tracker and forum for any unresolved audio bugs)

I think you can exclude the latter if you're using the playBackgroundMusic API to stream music instead of buffering it.